# How to get flat normals on a cube

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I am using OpenGL without the deprecated features and my light calculation is done on fragment shader. So, I am doing smooth shading.

My problem, is that when I am drawing a cube, I need flat normals. By flat normals I mean that every fragment generated in a face has the same normal.

My solution to this so far is to generate different vertices for each face. So, instead of having 8 vertices, now I have 24(6*4) vertices.

But this seems wrong to me, replicating the vertexes. Is there a better way to get flat normals?

Update: I am using OpenGL version 3.3.0, I do not have support for OpenGL 4 yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do the lighting in camera-space, you can use dFdx/dFdy to calculate the normal of the face from the camera-space position of the vertex.

So the fragment shader would look a little like this.

```
varying vec3 v_PositionCS; // Position of the vertex in camera/eye-space (passed in from the vertex shader)

    void main()
    { 
      // Calculate the face normal in camera space
      vec3 normalCs = normalize(cross(dFdx(v_PositionCS), dFdy(v_PositionCS)));

      // Perform lighting 
      ...
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain better what is dFdx/dFdy and why does it work? It is the direction of the surface?

Comment: The compute the gradients, given an input value.  So in this case; dfdx computes the gradient along the x-axis in view-space and dfdy calculates the gradient along the y-axis.  

And from these two gradient vectors, you can then calculate the normal, which should be the same for all the vertices on the triangle.

Comment: I'll just add; it's not always clear how exactly GPU will implement the calculation of the gradients, but you can assume that in this case, they are the X & Y gradients of the triangle in view-space most likely on the change of position of the neighboring pixels or vertices.

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/165360-Access-to-triangle-normals-rather-than-vertex has a similar answer but shows how to pass the value from the vertex shader.

Comment: AFIK the gradients are computed numerically by evaluating adjacent pixels. Even if adjacent pixels (in 2x2 "quad"s) aren't needed fragments are computed, called "helper" pixels. I think this is commonly used for mipmapping behind the scenes when you call `texture()`.

Comment: @JamesSteele This is beautiful. Not only it solves the problem in a super clever way, it aslo moves vertex normals calculation entirely into shader code.

Answer (score 6):

Since a geometry shader can "see" all three vertices of a triangle at once, you can use a geometry shader to calculate the normals and send them to your fragment shader. This way, you don't have to duplicate vertices.

```
// Geometry Shader

#version 330 

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 gNormal;

// You will need to pass your untransformed positions in from the vertex shader
in vec3 vPosition[];

uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 side2 = vPosition[2] - vPosition[0];
    vec3 side0 = vPosition[1] - vPosition[0];
    vec3 facetNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * cross(side0, side2));

    gNormal = facetNormal;
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gNormal = facetNormal;
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gNormal = facetNormal;
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Comment: I also checked, even though this code was originally written for version 400, it should work correctly with version 330 as is.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to pass MV-matrix and the unrotated AxisAligned coordinate to the fragment shader:

```
 attribute aCoord;
 varying vCoord;
 void main() {
    vCoord = aCoord;
    glPosition = aCoord * MVP;
 }
```

At Fragment shader one can then identify the normal by calculating the dominating axis of vCoord, setting that to 1.0 (or -1.0) and the other coordinates to zero -- that is the normal, which has to be rotated by the MV -matrix.