# WebGL Flat Shading

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a vertex shader and fragment shader using the `flat` qualifier, and for complicated hacky reasons explained near the end of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6PEfzQVpvM, I want to change the WebGL flat shading provoking vertex, which is the vertex number that WebGL will use when passing varying colors. (my shader is like this):

```
// ...
flat out vec3 pass_vertexColor;
// ...
```

and I know in OpenGL you can change the provoking vertex like this:

```
glProvokingVertex(1 /* 2, 3 */); // i think
```

But I don't think there is an equivalent in WebGL yet. So my question is:

**What is the default WebGL Provoking Vertex?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebGL 1.0 does not support flat shading. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101023/flat-shading-in-webgl) for a workaround.

WebGL 2.0 has flat shading. It has the same default as regular OpenGL - the provoking vertex is the last vertex of the triangle. It appears this cannot be changed in WebGL 2.0 as `ProvokingVertex()` is not exposed through the WebGL 2.0 API.

Note that even in desktop OpenGL, the provoking vertex can either be the first or last vertex of the triangle (with last being the default). It cannot be the middle vertex.

Comment: I know that only webgl 2.0 has flat shading. webgl has no provokingVertex method, only opengl

Comment: You're right about `glProvokingVertex()`. It is available in OpenGL ES 3.0, on which WebGL 2.0 is based, but is not available in WebGL 2.0. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That it's missing [seems like a bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/2567)

Comment: Update: that function, `ProvokingVertex` while it exists in [the ES 3.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) it does not exist in [the ES 3.0 header file](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php#headers3)!???! Checking the ES 3.1 and 3.2 specs the function is removed and instead a table lists for each primitive type where the value comes from and there's no way to set it. For `TRIANGLES` it's the last vertex of each triangle.